# Android Search widget showing suggestions on second character, need to show one user clicks the search view

Tags: android, search, searchview, android-search, android-searchmanager

I am trying to map a arraylist of strings to searchview adapter using a custom adapter. I have tried so many links, everything is working fine except that the suggestions layout is coming when user types the second character. I want to show the suggestions layout when user taps on the search widget. Did anybody faced this issue. any suggestions?